# How to make tfjs not ignore gpu device?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am running tfjs in a container from an official image of tensorflow-gpu. It logs to the console the following message:

```
Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: Tesla M60, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 5.2) with Cuda compute capability 5.2. The minimum required Cuda capability is 6.0.
```

The host is an aws vm with a Tesla M60. How can i compile tfjs to run with cuda capability 5.2?
Thanks in advance